# Jquery: Can I refer to a selector not present in the default HTML?

Tags: jquery-selectors

Sorry, this is probably a noob question. Could'nt find the source of my problem, or helpful info in SO (or elsewhere!).

I'm practising my newly acquired Jquery skills (?) on a small contact list demo project, which basically includes a table and a simple form to populate it. The project includes an HTML file, a CSS stylesheet, and some Javascript and Jquery magic in a .JS file.

**EDIT:** Here's a [jsFiddle I've created for this](http://jsfiddle.net/ibanner/Abxzx/3/).

By default, when the page first loads, the table is empty and a placeholder text is shown:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th id="col_lastName">Last Name</th>
        <th id="col_firstName">First Name</th>
        <th id="col_email">E-Mail</th>
        <th id="col_mobile">Mobile</th>
        <th id="col_actions">Actions</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr id="placeholder">
        <td colspan="5">No contacts yet. Feel free to add your friends!</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Upon submittion of the form, using Jquery I set the placeholder to disappear and a new table row is appended:

```
$("tbody").append(
    "<tr><td>" +  $("#last_name").val() +
    "</td><td>" + $("#first_name").val() +
    "</td><td><a href='mailto:" + $("#email").val() + "'>" + $("#email").val() + "</a>" +
    "</td><td>" + $("#mobile").val() +
    "</td><td><p class='remove_link'>Remove</p></td></tr>");
```

I would like it to include a link to remove the current row, so I wrote a function that's triggered by clicking the `<p class="remove_link">"Remove"</p>` text that was part of the string appended upon form submittion. However I can't seem to be able to make it clickable with Jquery. I wrote this:

```
$(".remove_link").click(function(){
    // just for chaecking the selector is ok
    console.log("remove clicked"); 
});
```

But on the actual page the "Remove" isn't clickable at all.

Does it have anything to do with the fact that the class doesn't appear in the default HTML and is only declared in the appended code?

Of course, it could also mean my syntax is wrong, but I can't figure this out!

Comment: Can a <p> tag even be made clickable without putting an <a> around it?

Comment: it would be best to create a jsfiddle entry so that it is easier for people to help you debug what's going on.

Comment: and in any case, instead of making a <P> element clickable, use a button or link...

Comment: and last, in response to timbck2, yes, try this code: <p onclick="alert('hello');">click me</p>

Comment: Thankd @TheZuck - [Here's the jsFiddle for this issue](http://jsfiddle.net/ibanner/Abxzx/3/). I'd appreciate if you could take a look. Anyway as for alternatives to `<p>` as the clickable element: (1) **Button:** I don't what it to look like a button - can I "un-buttonize" a button in CSS? (2) **link** - thought about it. but what should I put in under href?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the element you are trying to bind the event to does not exist yet when you perform the binding you need to set up a future delgate using `.on()`

```
$("table").on('click',".remove_link",function () {
      console.log("remove clicked");
});
```

Note that the important trick is to start the binding from an existing element (in this case the table)

I updated your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Abxzx/4/

Comment: Thanks, @Variant! I tried to fiddle around with `.on()` for hours, but could make this work. I think what drove me crazy was not being able to understand why I couldn't bind this event to other elements that _are_ present, but what I only now understand is that I should have binded the event to a **specific** element. I now understand why selecting didn't do the trick - the _specific_ "tr" where my "p" was about to be injected to - did'nt exist in the DOM! This might sound trivial to you, but it took me hours to figure out, with your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

well, I think I have a lead for an answer for this. In the page dealing with The `.on()` method on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_on.asp) there's a reference (down belew) to the fact that this method can also "work for elements not yet created". From this I deduct that the simple `.click()` just won't do. I'll try again with `.on()` tomorrow and will report my findings.

Meanwhile, if there's someone here more experienced in Jquery, I'd appreciate your opinion/advice.